# Optimisation JS and css when all are merge in one file?

Tags: javascript, css, optimization

On my web site, I use a compressor to have only one file CSS and JS to optimise loading.

So, what are the consequences? All my scripts or CSS rules are read, always, on each page!

How can I define CSS for only one specific page? I use a cheat: I define id="PAGE_NAME" on body for example, but I don't think it's the best way because all the rules are read, a lot of which are for another page...

**How can I optimise this?**

For JS now, i use variable like "PAGE", and i have to include "if(PAGE == 'foo') {...script...}" so only the relevant scripts are executed but it's pretty dirty :s

How can I manage that?

Comment: Why do you concatenate the CSS of different pages if they don't have most in common ?

Comment: For the JS, if you want to concatenate, you may call functions from your HTML pages instead of executing directly some code in your js files.

Comment: @dystroy because it's being cached by the browser.

Comment: because concatenate and minimify is standards thing to do for optimize (cash, loading, number http requests...). JS like CSS must not be in HTML...